# Disable Split-Screen/Multi-Window for apps

Tags: 7.0-nougat, multi-window

Forgive me if this is a duplicate post as I couldn't find a solution in post history.

My question is concerning Split-screen/multi-screen functionality in Android Nougat. Is there a way to disable app split screen functionality? My device is a rooted Motorolla Nexus 6 with Android 7.0. I was wondering if there was an adb command or a line I can add to the build.prop file to disable multi-window in the system.

If it is easier, is there a way to simply change what occurs when the recent app button is held?

Answer (score 1):

> [Is] there a way to simply change what occurs when the recent app button is held?

You can tweak the Overview (Recent) button for long-press event using [GravityBox [N]](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.nougat.gravitybox). GravityBox requires a comapatible [Xposed Framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811).

In GravityBox module, go to *Navigation keys actions* → scroll to *Recents key* → tap *Long-press action* → choose an appropriate action.

From then on, long-pressing the Overview button would not show spit-screen mode.

Tested on Nexus 6 running stock Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the information! After looking at your answer, I noticed there is a download for Xsposed framework ported within the Magisk Manager. Do you know if this version of Xsposed is compatable with GravityBox? If not do you know of a good guide so I can be sure to set up the Xsposed framework safely and correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on [setprop multiwindow nougat disable](https://www.google.com/search?q=setprop+multiwindow+nougat+disable) turned up a Reddit [I managed to disable multiwindow in Nougat!](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS7/comments/5ysanj/i_managed_to_disable_multiwindow_in_nougat/). The part matching your question is:

> Set the secure setting "set_multiwindow_feature_list" to " " (space).

The command-line for that would be:

```
> adb shell
$ settings put secure set_multiwindow_feature_list " "
```

The Reddit post also includes a howto for Tasker.

Note that I've not verified the above as I have no Nougat device to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information I particularly like the adb shell settings list the reddit post mentioned.  Unfortunately, after a little digging, it appears like his solution does not work for my Nexus 6 device as there is no "multiwindow_feature_list" attribute to modify with adb for google devices.

Comment: Scanning the Reddit again it seems ir refers to a Samsung device. Yuck, why does Samsung always do its own thing – and always "just the other way around" (like putting the "back" key on the right side when every other device has it on the left)? Sorry it didn't work out then. I still leave the answer stay as it might come handy to some Sammy users.

Comment: There are also apps available on Play store for Samsung users but none for others :(

Answer (score -1):

There's no setup for Xposed. If you're rooted with the excellent work of topjohns Magisk, just flash the latest Xposed. If your ROM is compatible it will boot GREEN. Be sure to give it root privalages and you may need to reboot twice. Hard boot suggested. As for disabling your split window stuff, look for it in build.prop if there's a 1 next to it, replace with with "0". Better yet, flash AEX ROM and enable, disable whatever you want. Oh and Xposed is system-less within Magisk. Be sure to flash Magisk Manager "mm" and follow the super simple set up guide. It'll save your ass. And I'm sure you know to save any changes you make to your build.prop as 0644.

Comment: Build.prop can also be edited systemless.